# Nested ng-repeat and radio or checkbox inputs not working

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to show list of questions and their choices by nested ng-repeat, I have seen plenty of similar questions but still could not fix my issue. My issue here is I could see the list of questions but the choices are not getting displayed and in the developer tools I could only see the commented ng-repeat line in place of choices.

Here is my View

```
<div ng-repeat ="question in questions track by $index" class="panel panel-default" ng-show="showQuestions">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="panel-title">
            <a href="div#{{$index}}" class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" >
                {{question.QuestionTxt}}
            </a>
            <div class="row height"></div>
            <div class="row" ng-show="question.QuestionTypeTxt == 'RadioButton'">
                    <div class="col-xs-3" ng-repeat ="answer in questions.QuestionAnswers track by $index">
                        <input type="radio" ng-model="selectedChoice.choice" ng-value="{{answer.AnswerTxt}}" name="{{question.QuestionTxt}}"/>{{answer.AnswerTxt}}
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" ng-show="question.QuestionTypeTxt == 'Checkbox'">
                    <div class="col-xs-3" ng-repeat ="answer in questions.QuestionAnswers track by $index">
                        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedChoice.choice" ng-value="{{answer.AnswerTxt}}" name="{{question.QuestionTxt}}"/>{{answer.AnswerTxt}}
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my Controller

```
$scope.questions = [];
                $scope.selectedChoice = { choice:"" };

$scope.addQuestions = function () {
       $scope.showQuestions = true;
        rmat3Service.getQuestionsForSection().then(function (data) {
              angular.forEach(data,function(a) {
                     $scope.questions.push(a);
               });
        });
}
```

This is my Json data:

```
var questions = new List<Question>();
var answers = new List<QuestionAnswer>();
answers.Add(new QuestionAnswer()
{
     AnswerTxt = "Yes",
});
answers.Add(new QuestionAnswer()
{
     AnswerTxt = "No"
});
answers.Add(new QuestionAnswer()
{
     AnswerTxt = "Yes Verified"
});
answers.Add(new QuestionAnswer()
{
     AnswerTxt = "Not Applicable"
});
questions.Add(new Question()
{
     QuestionId = 1,
     QuestionTxt = "Are aisles clear of product on the floor?",
                    QuestionTypeTxt = "RadioButton",
                    QuestionAnswers = answers
});
questions.Add(new Question()
{
     QuestionId = 2,
     QuestionTxt = "Automated Car Wash",
     QuestionTypeTxt = "Checkbox",
     QuestionAnswers = answers
});
return Json(questions, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Can you verify what you have by `console.log($scope.questions)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're attempting to loop `questions.QuestionAnswers` which doesn't exist. It should be `question.QuestionAnswers`:

```
<div class="col-xs-3" ng-repeat ="answer in question.QuestionAnswers track by $index">
```